# Actions memory management: when are they released?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

When you add an action to a sprite, since most things in Cocos are autoreleased, is it then released after it completes? Or, because you added it to a node, is it retained by the node?

If the action then ends, either due to completing on its own or because you stop it yourself, is it then released or is it still available to be run later?

I ask because I want to know if you need to recreate actions to reuse them, or if you can simply reference their tag and start and stop them at will whenever you want. Of if they repeat, if you can simply get them by tag number and then run them again; it's not clear the "correct" way to go about this. Thanks for help.

Comment: what's motivation for wanting to reuse actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that when you create and run an action on a sprite, the action is added to `CCActionManager`, which is a singleton that will manage the actions for you. This includes releasing all of them when the `CCACtionManager` itself is released and also when the action is done.

This is the relevant code about the latter (from CCActionManager.m):

```
-(void) update: (ccTime) dt
{
for(tHashElement *elt = targets; elt != NULL; ) {   
    ...
    if( ! currentTarget->paused ) {

        // The 'actions' ccArray may change while inside this loop.
        for( currentTarget->actionIndex = 0; currentTarget->actionIndex < currentTarget->actions->num; currentTarget->actionIndex++) {
                           ....

            if( currentTarget->currentActionSalvaged ) {
                              ....
                [currentTarget->currentAction release];

            } else if( [currentTarget->currentAction isDone] ) {
                                  .... 
                CCAction *a = currentTarget->currentAction;
                currentTarget->currentAction = nil;
                [self removeAction:a];
            }
                .....
        }
    }
```

After doing some [research](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/3192), it seems that the topic of reusing and action is on shaky grounds. Anyway, you can read here what the [cocos2d best practices suggest](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide%3abest_practices#actions). IMO, I would not try and reuse an action...

Comment: looks like a better way is an answer here that suggests you just put your action creation and running in an update method and then simply schedule that method and unschedule it so it runs once, then just schedulate it any time you want to "reuse" an action: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/2701#post-16778

Answer (score 1):

When you pass the reference to the CCNode with the runAction message it hands it to a CCActionManager which sends the action a retain message. Once the action is completes it sends a release message. If you want to keep using an action you should keep a reference to it and send your own retain and release messages.

The actions are designed to be lightweight "fire and forget" objects. I wouldn't worry about it unless you're noticing performance problems and trace it back to them.

Answer (score 1):

Actions are one-shot classes. Once the action is "done" or has been stopped or the node that runs the action is deallocated the action will be (auto-)released.

If you need to re-use actions, there's only a rather scary solution available: you need to send the corresponding init… message to the existing action again. You will also have to manually retain the action.

Actions are very lightweight classes, their runtime performance is comparable to allocating a new NSObject instance. Personally, I think if you're in performance trouble because you're creating and releasing many actions, I would say that you're using actions too much and should look for a better solution.

Comment: i'm interested in pausing and restarting animations. since the animation is in a CCRepeatForever action, I thought i could stop the action by its tag, and then restart it as well, but if instead if I create an instance variable that points to it, give it `retain` then I could start and stop it whenever I wanted without recreating the animation each time, right?